# replace direct link to amazon s3

Tags: wordpress, redirects

I moved my downloadable files to amazon s3 and used that link from my wordpress site. I realized that if I use amazon link, google analytics wont be able to track all the files. correct? whats the easiest way to make a redirection to use a url pointed to my domain and redirects to amazon link when user clicks on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct but also incorrect at the same time.

**Hotlinking**

If people are hotlinking to the file, i.e not visiting your site first then the GA will not be loaded therefor it will not be tracked.

**Page Visit Downloads**

If they visit your page and then click a download button for example this event will be tracked no problem regardless if it includes an external file.

**Hotlinking Prevention**

The question [how do I prevent hotlinking on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948823/how-do-i-prevent-hotlinking-on-amazon-s3-without-using-signed-urls) has been asked a few times and I suggest you dig around on the net if you want to prevent hotlinking, personally I don't bother. I can see the stats of my downloads from the S3 without GA.